# Some subtlety of GWT compilation - "gwt module may need to be (re)compiled."

Tags: gwt

I'm deploying an app to GAE.  I have a single project setup in Eclipse, with three separate GWT modules, each with its own HTML page, entry point, etc.  They share a lot of code.

When I deploy the app to appengine, TWO of the modules work fine.  I can access their HTML pages perfectly.  The third gives me the error that "gwt module 'xyz' may need to be (re)compiled."  I have tried recompiling and redeploying twice, to no avail, and have no ideas about moving forward.

Other threads about this problem point to the gwt.codeserver argument, and indeed, if I add that argument, the bad module runs... but it seems to be running *in dev mode!*  If this is true, I'm a little bit apalled, since I don't want to serve dev mode code to anyone.

Any suggestions would be welcome - my work is basically entirely stalled on this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found my own answer: in my case, the error was not being caused by a missing *gwt.codesvr* argument (as in all other cases I found referenced online).  Instead, a module rename-to attribute I added in my module definition *gwt.xml* file caused a mixup.  I'll recount the whole story in case it helps others understand more.

1. I created a new module and a new HTML page.
2. The module's name was **com.reallylong.and.unwieldy**, and my HTML page pulled in the javascript from **com.reallylong.and.unwieldy/com.reallylong.and.unwieldy.nocache.js**.
3. Later, I got smart and used the *rename-to* attribute to rename
   **com.reallylong.and.unwieldy** to "short," *not changing* my HTML code.
   I forgot.

This didn't affect me for several days, since I guess eclipse is smart enough to recompile both files, or something.  Who knows.  I suspect the *gwt.codesvr* argument was actually enabling this obscuring behavior, loading the code from dev mode instead of from the js file.

Ultimately, the fix was simple: I changed my HTML file so that the js was being pulled from **short/short.nocache.js**. 
And it worked! 
Woohoo!

Answer (score 2):

Adding these lines to XXX.gwt.xml file worked for me: (GWT version 2.5.1)

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled"
    value="true" />
<set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />
```

Comment: Worked for me too. I used GWT 2.7.0, and without this exported war (with properly compiled GWT) did work in IE only. With this it works for Chrome and Firefox too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that throws this message.

```
function B() {
    var b = false;
    try {
    var c = Window.location.search;
    return (c.indexOf("gwt.hosted=") != -1 
        || (c.indexOf("gwt.codesvr=") != -1
        || Window.external && Window.external.gwtOnLoad)) 
        && c.indexOf("gwt.hybrid") == -1
    } catch (a) {}
    B = function () {
    return b
    };
    return b
}
// and later, if B() returns false, show recompile error
if (!B()) {
    try {
    alert(Pb);
    return;
    }
  ...
}
```

Thus, to prevent the compiler message

- don't have gwt.hybrid in the URL
- AND DON't have gwt.hosted=
- OR get.codesvr=
- OR a Window.external.getOnLoad method

That being said, when I don't have this problem, this code **is not** compiled into the *.nocache.js file, so that is where the true bugaboo lies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in two steps:

1. in eclipse click on the red icon "GWT compile project"
2. in eclipse right clik -> run as Maven package

Comment: Didn't do anything for me. :/