# GWT module may need to be (re)compiled REDUX

Tags: gwt, maven

When running in compiled mode I get this dreaded GWT Module 'mymodule' may need to be (re)compiled dialog message.

I've compiled a list of the things that others have suggested to try when given this error message by GWT running in compiled mode.  I've opened the WAR file created by maven and all the files are in the right place.  I confirmed this against another GWT maven project that does not get this error.  However, none of the below suggestions have corrected the problem.  Nor have I been able to identify what difference is missing between these two projects -- the one that works and mine that will not run in compiled mode.

- [does name in html launch page match the module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688067/some-subtlety-of-gwt-compilation-gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled)
- Lots of lame suggestions to add the gwt.codesrv query string param onto the URL.  However, the point is to run without in compiled mode.  Obviously, I don't want to run in hosted mode.  That works.  I'm trying to run in compiled mode in Tomcat.
- Clearing browser cache? -- nope.  didn't help
- I have **not** over-riden the "user.agent" property in mymodule.gwt.xml
- [add to the maven-clean-plugin configuration your eclipse output directory: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4310)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have you started the DevMode using your `src/main/webapp` as the "war folder"? or in other words, is there a `*.nocache.js` in your `src/main/webapp`? In that case, this file will overwrite the one produced by the GWT compiler as called by the gwt-maven-plugin.

The `*.nocache.js` generated by the DevMode (when no one exists, generated by a previous GWT compilation) contains only the necessary bits to launch the DevMode, and will otherwise fail with the above-mentioned error.

Comment: good idea, and yes I do.  I had added an additional configuration for maven-clean-plugin to delete src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes.  After your suggestion I just added src/main/webapp/SpringGridGui as I should have from the start.  deleting this working directory was the fix.  Thank you Thomas!

Comment: Much better to follow the recommendations and launch the DevMode with the `target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/` as the "war folder" http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_with_maven

Comment: Where in this link :  code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_with_maven
do they mention anything about setting the war directory for DevMode?

Comment: See http://web.archive.org/web/20130619170526/https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven

Comment: I don't understand where's the answer in this post. So should I delete the file? Or what am I supposed to do? (actually deleting the file rendered application non-functional)

Comment: When using Maven, you shouldn't generate output into your input folders. You shouldn't create a *.nocache.js in your sources, it should only live in your "target". You shouldn't use `src/main/webapp` as a target of anything, it's input, not output.

Answer (score 16):

Look for a file called `<MODULE_NAME>.nocache.js` in `src/main/webapp/<MODULE_NAME>` and delete/rename it.

Then do your mvn package and all 'should' be fine.

This problem can occurs when you run Dev mode in Eclipse. Eclipse will generate the nocache.js file and put it under the `src/main/webapp` directory.

Then when you run `mvn pacakge`, the maven plugin create the deployment `nocache.js` and puts it in the right place, but then when it packages files into a war it then over-rights it's deployment `nocache.js` with the one Eclipse created - bummer!

Comment: This was so helpful, thanks for the explanation.  Had this problem after following this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12430221/320399

Answer (score 5):

I found the same issue in DevMode if there was a static link to another page in the application (i.e. myModule2.html). Because it lacked the *?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997* string, it was interpreted as a static (already compiled) GWT app, which it was not, throwing the error code you mentioned.

[image]

Of course the solution is not to use hardcoded literal links, but let GWT make them for you. Hope that helps someone.

**UPDATE:**

This is the code that throws this error in the standard GWT *.nocache.js file.

```
function B() {
    var b = false;
    try {
    var c = Window.location.search;
    return (c.indexOf("gwt.hosted=") != -1 
        || (c.indexOf("gwt.codesvr=") != -1
        || Window.external && Window.external.gwtOnLoad)) 
        && c.indexOf("gwt.hybrid") == -1
    } catch (a) {}
    B = function () {
    return b
    };
    return b
}
// and later, if B() returns false, show recompile error
if (!B()) {
    try {
    alert(Pb);
    return;
    }
  ...
}
```

Thus, to prevent the compiler message

- don't have gwt.hybrid in the URL
- AND DON't have gwt.hosted=
- OR get.codesvr=
- OR a Window.external.getOnLoad method

So, in the case of the popup, some server code was redirecting a DevMode session url, but not adding back the "codesvr=" parameter, hence the warning was shown.

Answer (score 2):

Have you compiled the source? This is a surprisingly non-obvious step.  If you're using eclipse, you can compile by clicking the red toolbox icon.

Comment: The mvn package command creates the war for running compiled mode.  I've opened the resulting war, and seen the mymodule.nocache.html and the *.cache.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to run `mvn gwt:compile` additionally to the usual `mvn clean install package`, as the GWT-compilation is NOT part of the maven-package-phase.
This solves the annoying Javascript-(re)compile-error.

Comment: Is mvn gwt:compile the same as: right-click project -> Google -> GWT Compile?  I think it is?  If so, then this was my solution (I wasn't running Maven package)...

Comment: See my similar solution as this to another similar Question for more details:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35387271/1357094

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Doing `mvn clean install` on my GWT project got me a war file, which upon deploying in tomcat resulted in the same "GWT Module 'mymodule' may need to be (re)compiled" dialog message. I also did all the mentioned stuff in here without any success.

Doing `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true` did the job for me.
OR 
Doing `mvn clean install` without invoking the generated test URL (sth. like this: `http://<localIp>:53701/mymoduleJUnit.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=<localIp>:53697`)

The test phase obviously did overwrite my initially created `*.nocache.js` via some fancy development mode url, thus packaging me a wrong `*.nocache.js` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

My Dev mode was correctly configured and above solution didn't work. Following did solve the issue though.

Multiple steps:

1. Update Project properties -> deployment Assembly using [Deploy GWT maven project with eclipse deploys webapp directory instead of target/project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825018/deploy-gwt-maven-project-with-eclipse-deploys-webapp-directory-instead-of-target)
2. mvn clean package
3. mvn gwt:compile
4. In eclipse, click on 'GWT Compile Project' -> Advacned -> Remove '-war src/main/webapp' argument and hit compile.

Output should be like this - 
Linking into target/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ModuleName

... and deployment works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This could apply to all other valid Answers here too:  Sometimes you may need to just do a hard/cache browser refresh (ctrl+F5) after following one of them.