# gwt beginner- error "could not find any host pages in project'

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I m trying to create a GWT app- it has a single HTML file (main.html) and the java class is main.java.

In Eclipse, I did right click-> GWT -> Module and defined the new module correctly.

However after adding some code, when I try to run the app in Dev mode, I get the error

```
"Could Not find any host pages in project <project-name> "
```

I have simply added some code to main.java, then saved it and tried to run the app in dev mode... What am I doing wrong here? Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Could you post the *.gwt.xml file contents for the module in question?  Also, the contents of your web.xml might help in narrowing down the issue...

Comment: This answer solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12430221/67225

Answer (score 25):

Normally it could happen if WAR Directory is not defined for this project.

So go to Project properties --> Google(Web Application),

1. Check  the checkbox whcih says "This project has a WAR directory"
2. In WAR Directoy textbox, browse and give path to your project webapp something like "src/main/webapp"
3. Check the Checkbox "Launch and Deploy from this directoy"

This should fix your problem.

Comment: This helped me fix my problem when re-importing the project. I also had to add another gwt-servlet.jar, because the version had changed. So don't forget dependencies. Thanks for this! This should be marked as the correct answer imo.

Comment: This can cause some issues when running (later on) in regulare _compiled_ mode.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5745870