# "GWT module may need to be (re)compiled" when deployed into the Tomcat and the war is generated with maven

Tags: gwt, spring-mvc, mojo, gwt-2.4, gwt-maven-plugin

I got the issue( "GWT module 'SmartWPS' may need to be (re)compiled") while accessing the url. I have generated the war file by running maven-clean-install. I placed the same war file in the /webapp folder.

I have developed application using GWT with client side GIN as Dependency Injection and server side as the Spring Dependency Injection. When I am running the maven-clean-install, war file is generating successfully. After placing the war file in the /webapp **folder then i am seeing following error in the tomcat logs folder,**

> Jul 18, 2012 8:43:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'urlMapping' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'empDetailsController' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet.xml]: Cannot
>   create inner bean
>   'com.infor.ion.boddesk.ui.sample.server.EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl#ca56214'
>   of type
>   [com.infor.ion.boddesk.ui.sample.server.EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl]
>   while setting bean property 'remoteService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'com.infor.ion.boddesk.ui.sample.server.EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl#ca56214'
>   defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.infor.ion.boddesk.ui.sample.server.EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)

**My spring-servlet.xml file is like as pasted below,**

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
>
> ```
> <!-- The application context definition for the DispatcherServlet -->
>
> <!-- Maps the request through to a concrete controller instance -->
> <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
>     <property name="mappings">
>         <value>
>         <!-- /**/SampleApp.rpc=sampleAppController -->
>         /**/empDetails.rpc=empDetailsController
>         </value>
>     </property>
> </bean>
>
> <!-- GwtRpcController wraps our service in order to decode the incoming -->
> <!-- request then delegates processing of the call to the POJO service -->
> <!-- and then encodes the return value forwarding the response. -->    <!--<bean id="sampleAppController" class="com.infor.ion.boddesk.server.GwtRpcController">
>     <property name="remoteService">
>         <bean class="com.infor.ion.boddesk.server.sampleapp.SampleAppService" />
>     </property>
> </bean>  -->      <bean id="empDetailsController" class="com.infor.ion.boddesk.ui.sample.server.GwtRpcController">
>     <property name="remoteService">
>         <bean class="com.infor.ion.boddesk.ui.sample.server.EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl"
> ```
>
> />

When enabling with maven iam facing with all these problems, with build.xml, it was just successful and even within jetty server is running successfully.

Thanks,
Saritha

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT module may need to be (re)compiled REDUX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719118/gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled-redux)

Answer (score 0):

Clean the temp files(Run > %temp%)
Clean your project(in your IDE)
Clean the browsers' cache.(Use CCleaner)
Compile the project once again.