# Deploy GWT app in a CMS

Tags: java, gwt, content-management-system

I tried deploying my GWT app in a CMS however here's the error it throws when accessed:

```
GWT module 'app' may need to be (re)compiled
```

I have placed the compiled 'app' folder in the resource folder of the CMS where it is accessed like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="file/theme/gwt/app/app.nocache.js"></script>
```

I tried checking if the `app.nocache.js` is accessible in the browser and it is.

This app works when I run it as Eclipse GWT project or through maven `gwt:run`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps this topic may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719118/gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled-redux