# GWT ECLIPSE - module 'package.module' may need to be (re)compiled when linked

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I am getting this `module 'tdlat.AllTasks' may need to be (re)compiled`, when I link from my home page (ToDoList.html) to my 'AllTasks' page (AllTasks.html). But when I run directly from the AllTasks page I do not get this error. I am running this in Development Mode.

- I have read and followed the steps from
  [GWT module may need to be (re)compiled REDUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719118/gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled-redux),
  and I am still getting the same problem.
- I have tried clearing out my browser cache.

**FILES PACKAGE**
[image]

[image: Error]

**Code where the URL links to the error**

```
Anchor link = new Anchor(true);
horizontalPanel_1.add(link);
link.setHTML("All Tasks");
link.setHref("AllTasks.html");
```

My link is linked to a separate module.

EDIT

> link.setHref("AllTasks.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997")

Fixed my problem, but I am not too sure how to make this work also in production mode.
Here is what I have so far.

```
if (GWT.isProdMode()){
    // What goes here? Thanks!      
}
else
{
    link.setHref("AllTasks.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
}
```

Thank you for the assistance! Please let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: you may need to do `link.setHref("AllTasks.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997")` for development mode (you can check this using `GWT.isProdMode()`). I'm not sure if this really is the problem, which is why this a comment, not an answer. But it doesn't hurt either way, especially if you plan to debug it.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I just corrected an error, i wrote "codesrv", "codesvr" would be correct.

Comment: Thanks that did fix the problem. How would I make this work for Production mode also? Thanks!

Comment: if (GWT.isProdMode()){
  What would go here?
  }else
  {
         link.setHref("AllTasks.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
  }

Comment: made it an answer and explained it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In development mode, you need to append the parameter `gwt.codesvr`. So, you can use

```
if(GWT.isProdMode()) {
   link.setHref("AllTasks.html");
} else {
   link.setHref("AllTasks.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
}
```

`GWT.isProdMode()` returns true in production mode and false when in development mode (127.0.0.1:8888) and is optimized by the GWT compiler, so everything in the `else` doesn't show up in the resulting JavaScript code, as if you just wrote `link.setHref("AllTasks.html")`. It is a neat tool for all kind of analyzing things in DevMode, without slowing down the production system.

Comment: Thank you for the assitance MarioP I appriciate it.