# GWT development mode application, display debug messages from GWT dev

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I am using GWT development mode.  As well as remote debugging through maven and Intellij.  E.G. I launch 'mvn gwt:debug -Dgwt.noserver=true'.  And then launch the remote debugging: '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000'

And then the GWT dev mode application launches when I visit the browser.  This is all working fine but I sometimes the compile process is slow.  Is there a flag that I can pass to GWT dev app for more debugging what is going on?  Can I print the 'compile' statements when it compiles GWT code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT module may need to be (re)compiled REDUX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719118/gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled-redux)

Comment: I want to display more message about the inner workings of the GWT development plugin.  Not necessarily address the compile message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the gwt-maven-plugin.  You can add 'logLevel=DEBUG' to the configuration settings to increase the logging for the GWT development mode.