# GWT 2.7 + GAE app looks for codeserver when deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin, gwt-super-dev-mode

## Why does appengine try to use Super Dev Mode?

Every time I deploy my GWT app to appengine and try to access it I get the white loading screen, then after about 20-30 seconds I get this message:

[image: Couldn't load project from Super Dev Mode server at appspot.com:9876. Please make sure the server is ready. Do you want to try again?]

I use maven with the [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) and [appengine-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/). Deploying using the [maven-gae-plugin](https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin) gives the same results.

If I switch back to using 2.6.1 versions of gwt and the gwt-maven-plugin it deploys ok, so it would seem it's something to do with the automatic dev mode launcher.

### Some of my pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/super</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/gwt</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${target.jdk}</source>
                    <target>${target.jdk}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- JUnit Testing - skip *.GwtTest cases -->
            <!-- 'mvn test' - runs the Jukito tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*GwtTest.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*JUnitTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- GWT -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <testTimeOut>180</testTimeOut>
                    <!-- With multiple tests use GwtTestSuite.java for speed -->
                    <includes>**/*GwtTest.java</includes>
                    <mode>htmlunit</mode>

                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xss1024k -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M</extraJvmArgs>
                    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                    <style>PRETTY</style>

                    <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>

                    <server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
                    <appEngineVersion>${gae.version}</appEngineVersion>
                    <appEngineHome>${gae.home}</appEngineHome>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Dappengine.sdk.root=${gae.home}</extraJvmArgs>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20</extraJvmArgs>
                    <port>8888</port>

                    <runTarget>Project.html</runTarget>
                    <modules>
                        <module>com.utilitiessavings.usavappv7.Project</module>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Google App Engine Deployment -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gae.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarSplitting>true</enableJarSplitting>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Google Web Toolkit dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google App Engine dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistence dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>${persistence-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>${objectify.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

### In my Project.gwt.xml

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```

(Tried removing this line but still got the same result)

### Environment

Eclipse Luna (4.4.1)

Maven 3.2.3 (3.2.1 Embedded)

m2eclipse 1.5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gwt:compile` tries to work "incrementally" by comparing the timestamp of the nocache.js file with the ones of the source files, and skipping GWT compilation if it thinks the output is up-to-date. **This is brittle** though. `gwt:run` (without `<superDevMode>false</superDevMode>`; and `gwt:run-codeserver` with `launcherDir`) will overwrite the nocache.js with a SuperDevMode-specific version, and this is likely to lead to `gwt:compile` skipping the compilation.

The takeaway is: when deploying or "releasing", make sure you first run `mvn clean` **or** force `gwt:compile` to run by passing `-Dgwt.compiler.force` to Maven.

Comment: Thanks, but I always run 'mvn clean' first and it has happened every time I've tried.

Comment: Could it just be https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745870/116472 ? (but with the nocache.js generated by SuperDevMode rather than classic DevMode, hence the difference in behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, I had the same problem, caused by the usage of a non-standard project structure.

Maven was copying the `.nocache` files in a directory different than `/target/`which prevented the `clean` plugin from cleaning the generated files.

Adding a new  with the directory where the files are copied solves the problem.