# Disabling GWT 2.7.0 Super Dev Mode

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I just start sdm with GWT 2.7.0. It seems now we don't need to have Start/Stop bookmarks and it will automatically happens, good news but sometime I want to switch to production mode on my local machine.

I cant dot it I just put -Dgwt.compiler.force in front ot "maven clean install" or just add `<superDevMode>false</superDevMode>` in maven POM but just getting "Could not load webapp from Super Dev Mode server ..." !!!!

How Can I avoid runing SDM ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you start (Super)DevMode? If outside Maven, with which `-war` argument? Could it be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719118/gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled-redux (the error message being different because of "classic" DevMode vs. SuperDevMode)

Comment: It is standard maven project, I am starting it with gwt:run and/or eclipse, in eclipse -war is addressing target exploded folder.

Comment: did you try adding -nosuperDevMode to programm arguments?