# Use Classic Dev Mode in GWT 2.7

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

This might be simple question but no luck.How to use Classic Dev mode in GWT 2.7 even i read about GWT SDM ([Disabling GWT 2.7.0 Super Dev Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393159/disabling-gwt-2-7-0-super-dev-mode)) and added –nosuperDevMode in Argument but still its behaving the same as Super Dev Mode. Any thought on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you are using Eclipse, try updating your GWT plugins. When updated, you should also see new radio buttons in the run/debug configurations to pick between classic mode or super dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but did you try adding :

```
<superDevMode>false</superDevMode>
```

To your GWT (gwt-maven-plugin) configuration ?